# how can I set a Python virtual environment in any shells (open, or that will be opened) based on changing projectile project

Tags: python, projectile

I'm using Projectile and pyenv-mode (https://github.com/proofit404/pyenv-mode).

pyenv-mode has projectile integration to update the virtual environment while switching projects. This is the code to do so:

```
(defun projectile-pyenv-mode-set ()
  "Set pyenv version matching project name.
Version must be already installed."
  (pyenv-mode-set (projectile-project-name)))

(add-hook 'projectile-switch-project-hook 'projectile-pyenv-mode-set)
```

I've enabled this code in my `init.el`. I'm not sure if or how this is supposed to integrate with shells (ansi-term and shell specifically), but I am trying to achieve the following:

- When switching to a new project

  - switch any open shell buffers to the new python venv (can clear the buffer if required)
  - ensure than any wheel buffers opened while in a project also activate with that virtual env

What actually happens is that I get my default system Python in these shells at all times, unless I manually activate a virtual environment from in one of them.

Comment: In what way is it not working for you at the moment?  Try using a shell and tell us what breaks!

Comment: I'll add this to the question, but the answer to your comment is that any shell has the system python, and not the virtualenv of the currently active project.

Comment: The problem is that `(pyenv-mode-set)` doesn't set the path, so in a shell you will always get the system version. I don't use pyenv nor projectile, but I did look at the `(pyenv-mode-set)` code here: https://github.com/proofit404/pyenv-mode/blob/master/pyenv-mode.el#L64-L69